# Namespace aware document returning empty NodeList

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse general XML containing namespace elements. However, getElementsByTagNameNS() always returns an empty NodeList. For example, the following code, in which I've hard-coded some SAML text, (because it has namespaces and was available) returns an empty NodeList:

```
NodeList test() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new StringInputStream(
                    "<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\" xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\">\n" +
                    "    <saml:Assertion>\n" +
                    "    </saml:Assertion>\n" +
                    "</samlp:Response>"
    ));

    return document.getElementsByTagNameNS("saml", "Assertion");
}
```

The thing is, I've set it as namespace aware. As near as I can tell, this should return a NodeList with one result.

**EDIT**

There are numerous similar questions, but they are all asked by people who had forgotten to enable namespace awareness.

**EDIT**

For precision's sake, I ran this code using open JDK 1.8.0.151.

Comment: I've simplified the XML for clarity. It still exhibits the same issue.

Comment: I had deleted my namespace bindings in my over-zealousness. I've re-added them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to getElementsByTagNameNS() is the namespace URI, not the prefix. So it should be

```
return document.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "Assertion");
```